# WP_Query: query posts by ids from array?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query

I did quite a bit of research but can't figure why this wouldn't work for me?

```
echo print_r($rel); // Array ( [0] => 63 [1] => 87 )

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'post_in' => $rel
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I don't get any posts returned? Any ideas how to only get the posts with the ids in the array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use [`post__in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) (double underscore) argument, instead of `post_in`:

```
echo print_r($rel); // Array ( [0] => 63 [1] => 87 )

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $rel
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you are unsure why an argument is not working, copy it's key name from manual and past it into you snippet.

Comment: @mathiregister u r welcome! :)

Comment: The above snippet throws an error (in wordpress 4.9.5 )and you have to use  'post__in' => array($rel)